# How to correctly call onClick method of a list item's child?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm having trouble getting an onClick method of a list item's child to work. Currently, when one of my list items is long clicked, an AppCompatImageView appears. Now I want to implement an onClick method for that element. At the moment, clicking that button / image throws an exception and crashes my app:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method deleteCurrentNote()(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'listItemDeleteButton'
```

This makes sense since the onClick method is currently implemented in the activity that displays the list. Where to put my deleteCurrentNote() method so this works correctly though?

Some of my code (abridged):

list_item_note.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemTags" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemDeleteButton"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/delete"
        android:onClick="deleteCurrentNote()"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NoteListActivity.java:

```
ListView listViewNotes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewNotes);

lazyAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this, notes);
listViewNotes.setAdapter(lazyAdapter);

listViewNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        currentNote = allNotes.get(position);

        AppCompatImageView deleteButton = (AppCompatImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemDeleteButton);
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deleteButton.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(5000);
        return true;
    }
});

...

public void deleteCurrentNote(View view) {
    ...
}
```

I can upload code from my LazyAdapter as well if it helps.

Also, another question, why does the animation on my deleteButton look weird?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxrRW.gif

It fades in quickly, then instantly disappears, only to the fade in slowly. How can I make it just fade in once, slowly?

Thanks for your time

Comment: update your adapter code...

Comment: What exactly do I have to do? Please be a little more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your own new `LazyAdapter` child class if you use some lib. Or change the code in this way if you use your own `LazyAdapter`:

```
    class newClass extends LazyAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnClickListener {

 @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        currentNote = allNotes.get(position);
        AppCompatImageView deleteButton = (AppCompatImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemDeleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deleteButton.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(5000);
        return true;
    }
}

 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteCurrentNote();


  }
    }
```

in your base code:
`lazyAdapter = new newClass(this, notes);`
`listViewNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(lazyAdapter );`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemTags" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemDeleteButton"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/delete"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this.

How's this though, within my getView()?

    `deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((NoteListActivity) activity).deleteCurrentNote();
        }
    });`
Here, `activity` is the activity that called LazyAdapter's constructor.

Comment: it seem yes. but i would suggest to path some parameter `((NoteListActivity) activity).deleteCurrentNote();` inside `deleteCurrentNote(yourparameter_id)`

Comment: I just tried your way and it worked perfectly. I will keep like that because it seems like a s smarter way to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
listViewNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        currentNote = allNotes.get(position);

        AppCompatImageView deleteButton = (AppCompatImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemDeleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteCurrentNote();
            }
        });
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deleteButton.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(5000);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Manually adding an onClickListener did the trick.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS CODE. It will consume a lot of memory

Comment: lots of listeners dramatically changes your memory usage

Comment: Alright, what do you suggest then? Your answer didn't seem to work

Comment: I've change my mind. You have to update your adapter code and implement onclick listeners (long click and simple tap) here